# htmlspecialchars expects parameter 1 to be string, array given laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Saludos a la comunidad Estoy tratando de implementar el paquete owen-it / laravel-auditing en mi proyecto. Sigo este ejemplo como base, este es el enlace: https://pusher.com/tutorials/realtime-audit-trail-laravel . En este caso, aplico la auditoría a mi modelo de publicaciones, para este ejemplo solo he cambiado el título de mi publicación. Al querer ver los resultados de la auditoría en mi vista audit.blade.php me sale el siguiente error:

> htmlspecialchars () expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ tecind \ resources \ views \ audits \ audit.blade.php)

Mi vista audit.blade.php es la siguiente:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('header')    

    <h1>
        AUDITORIA
        <small>Listado </small>
    </h1>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Inicio</a></li>
        <li class="active">Auditoria</li>
    </ol> 
@stop

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table" >
            <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Model</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
                <th scope="col">User</th>
                <th scope="col">Time</th>
                <th scope="col">Old Values</th>
                <th scope="col">New Values</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="audits">
            @foreach($audits as $audit)
                <tr>
                <td>{{ $audit->auditable_type }} (id: {{ $audit->auditable_id }})</td>
                <td>{{ $audit->event }}</td>
                <td>{{ $audit->user->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $audit->created_at }}</td>
                <td>
                    <table class="table">
                    @foreach($audit->old_values as $attribute => $value)
                        <tr>
                        <td><b>{{ $attribute }}</b></td>
                        <td>{{ $value }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table class="table">
                    @foreach($audit->new_values as $attribute => $value)
                        <tr>
                        <td><b>{{ $attribute }}</b></td>
                        <td>{{ $value }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </table>
                </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Creo que el problema esta cuando ingresa aquí:

```
   <td>
                    <table class="table">
                    @foreach($audit->old_values as $attribute => $value)
                        <tr>
                        <td><b>{{ $attribute }}</b></td>
                        <td>{{ $value }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table class="table">
                    @foreach($audit->new_values as $attribute => $value)
                        <tr>
                        <td><b>{{ $attribute }}</b></td>
                        <td>{{ $value }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </table>
                </td>
```

Esta es una imagen de mi tabla audits

[image: audits]

**ACTUALIZADO**

Lo estoy resolviendo de la siguiente manera:

```
<td>
                    <table class="table table-dark table-hover">
                    @foreach($audit->old_values as $attribute => $value)
                        @php 
                            $obj = array($value, true)

                        @endphp
                        @foreach($obj as $key=>$val)
                            <tr>
                            <td><b>{{ $key }}</b></td>
                            <td>{{   $val }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                    </table>
                </td>
```

El resultado en mi vista blade es el siguiente:

[image: blade.audit]

como ven pude mostrar los valores del campo old_values, como por ejemplo el nombre del post (Mi cuarto post),
ahora **no puedo mostrar el titulo ** en su lugar me muestra un 0.

```
{"title":"Mi cuarto post","published_at":"2019-11-21 00:00:00"}
```

**Como podria mostrar por ejemplo title y published_at??**

Comment: Alguno me podra sugerir alguna idea?